# Program to compute factorial produces output of 6 for factorial 1003

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

I have the code below which appears to work for calculating factorial.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
n=int(input("Input a number to compute the factiorial : "))
print(factorial(n))
```

e.g factorial 5 = 120. This works using the below code.

However, when I entered "1003" as input, using Python IDLE, the output was 6.

Can anyone explain this? Screenshot below.

important note: It only happens when I have run a couple of tests:

e.g. try 999, 1000 and then 9000 and then 1003. The 6 occurs as output on this last test. What is happening in IDLE to cause this?

[image]

Comment: It would seem your Python version doesn't not come with big number support. I can't reproduce this with Python 3.9.4 on macos.

Comment: surely this is a significant bug.....how could anyone be expected to test if the results were unreliable. I've never heard of "big number support" before...

Comment: I get "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" for n>998. Maybe this happens in your case but leads to a different faulty behavior? You can check that by calculating a more mild function instead (like sum of an arithmetic progression).

Comment: Try installing a more recent version of Python: 3.9.6 is currently out.

Comment: I can successfully calculate for 1000 and even 1003, but it is random.

Comment: ..but my question is regarding the workings of python and the editor itself. Why should it produce this result?What is happening? This could have very serious repercussions for data science....and many are still using older versions, so that doesn't solve the problem, sorry.

Comment: Did you try the inbuilt ```factorial``` method with the same inputs ? What do you get ?

Comment: Note that Ram means `math.factorial`.

Comment: Before you conclude that world economics is at stake, triple check your local Python installation: how was it installed, on what Windows version, what machine type (i.e. 32 bit, 64 bit); does the problem disappear with a more recent version of Python, how does it compare to `math.factorial` etc.

Comment: I can't reproduce with python 3.9.1. Does the problem only occur in IDLE? What happens when you run the program from the command line? You could perhaps search through https://bugs.python.org/ to see if any bug along this line was reported.

Comment: I can't explain why you get 6, but the call stack size of CPython defaults to around 1000, IIRC. It's probably no coincidence that things start getting messy around this number. You really shouldn't use recursion to be computing factorials. Compute it using a loop, and if you still get the same problem, then you've probably narrowed down the problem to big number support or a bad installation. OP, please share your Python version.

Comment: 3.9.0 ...question isn't about the best way to compute factorial but rather the inner workings of THIS version. It works fine on say, repl.it, but why is IDLE producing this result.

Comment: @Compoot: Could you verify what n is? Is `n == 1003` or `n == 3`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe JS solution will help you:

```js
function factorial (y){
    if (y ==0 || y ==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        f = y - 1;
        while (f >= 1) {
            y = y * f;
            f--;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
console.log(factorial(100));
```